# What number of bytes should I use to have a safe token?

Tags: node.js, security

I am implementing a magic link/passwordless authentication.

I am sending an email with a token generated via `crypto.randomBytes`, when the user clicks on the link, it is redirected to the app and the token is validated to make sure it is unique.
Does the number of bytes matter, and if yes what would be a good number?

Comment: This question is too broad for a single answer. Security depends on far more than a number of random bits. Generally speaking: Anything sent by email is completely insecure, no matter how random or how many bits it contains.

Comment: Thanks @Filmzy for your comment. I understand security is a broad question. I am using crypto.randomBytes and was investigating what number of bytes I should use and why? But I couldn't find definite answer to this question. The answers I found was 16, 20, 256. It wasn't clear for me why these numbers?

Comment: @anita as today we consider 128 bit (and more) as unfeasible to guess. 128 and 256 bits (16 or 32 bytes) are commonly used as many algorithms are defined to work with these block sizes

Comment: Well, the number of bits, and why, depends on what you're doing. If your only goal is to get a token that's hard to guess, then, as @gusto2 says, 128 bits should be sufficient. As for why, read up on the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). But this doesn't actually make it secure. Someone can still evesdrop your sent emails.

Comment: If you're not worried about guesses, and just need unique tokens, you can use an auto-increment counter, a time-based token, or even some piece of user-specific data (such as email address).

Comment: In any case, you should NOT consider any of these answers "secure". Depending on your use case, this may not matte. If it does matter, you should absolutely rely on some other method for actual security.

Comment: @Flimzy Auth0, does not seem as [sceptical](https://auth0.com/blog/is-passwordless-authentication-more-secure-than-passwords/), about email login, or I am missing some important piece of information?

Comment: @KevinAmiranoff: I don't know how Auth0 does it, but most passwordless auth systems use a combination of browser cookies, IP address, and short-lived tokens to provide adequate security. I.e. the token must be used within 30 minutes, and by the same browser/IP address that requested it. This reduces the attack surface area significantly.  And this is much more involved than just "how many random bits for a secure token?"

Comment: Yeah for sure I am implementing other methods for security. The question was about generating a token via crypto.randomBytes :)

Comment: @Anita: Again, the size of the token isn't the most important thing.

Comment: In such a scenario, the token itself is actually one of the least interesting parts. What matters more, from a security standpoint, is how easy it is to steal or forge the HTTP cookies and/or client IP address.

Comment: @Filmzy For sure. I do agree the token is not enough (nor important) for safe form of login. I was just asking about what number of bytes to pass for token and why. I will go with 16 or 32 as gusto2 suggested. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

> token is validated to make sure it is unique

maybe you could as well validate that it's not yet expired (define some validity to the token)

> Does the number of bytes matter, and if yes what would be a good number?

In security, size does matter. It is considered as unfeasible to guess if the random output is 128 bit long (=16 bytes), or 256 bit (=32 bytes) with safe margin.

As well you may add some integrity/authentication check, such as signature or hmac, if you use simple random number generator (not from any serious crypto library) or counter

Comment: Just don't be fooled into thinking that sending 128-bit random numbers by email is actually secure.

Comment: @Flimzy nobody claimed that. The question was about a random token. To have a solid and secure authentication, there are more things to ensure/assume (email security, session security,..). imho any provider not supporting/enforcing TLS even for emails should be out of business long time ago.

Comment: Your answer doesn't make that claim, but the question implies it. TLS for email is not sufficient for this type of security.

Comment: @Flimzy could you expand on your comment a little, please?